# I can not write translations in Language Designer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, android-edittext

In my Multi-Device Application in Delphi I want **change language**.

Thus, I have used a TLang component in my Form but I have a problem.

After double click in TLang component, the Language Designer window starts. I write two letter language code like 'en' and I click in 'Add' button. My problem is that **it not show the Edit Texts** to write the corresponding translations of each text:

[image]

This is the behavior that it should have:

[image]

I have tested to move the separator which appears in the header but this does not anything.

Anyone know why the Edit Texts is not showing in my Language Designer??

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in Delphi 10.1 Seattle on a Window 7 32 bit machine when testing with Android and Windows targets. Try to restart your IDE (optionally also your PC). If problem still exist, have you checked Embarcadero Quality Portal for a report. If not reported yet, please file a report.

Comment: I use Delphi 10.1 Seattle too, why you can not reproduce my issue?? It just create a Multi-Device Application, create a Form with some texts and add a TLang component. I have restart my PC and IDE and my problem stil exist ...

Comment: Do you have the *Starter* edition? That has only limited internationalizing support. [Reference](https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf), scroll down to "INTERNATIONAL DEVELOPMENT"

Comment: I do not have a Starter edition, I have an Architect registered version ...

Comment: That is OK then. I'm running out of ideas, sorry. A final guess from me would be that it is somehow related to your project. Does the translator misbehave equally for a new project?

Comment: I have created a new Multi-device Application and it does not work either. Also, I have created a new VCL Forms Application but it does not exist TLang component in this type of project.

Comment: I checked the quality portal and indeed the problem has been reported. See my answer. Sorry for indicating the version erroneously. What I originally tested with was Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: I reported my issue in Embarcadero Quality Portal after you said me, but I have not received any answer yet. I do not think that version Delphi 10 Seattle is the problem because I have seen some videos where TLang works in previous versions.

Comment: It was reported working in XE8. A regression is not uncommon unfortunately.

Comment: I do not understand ... What do you mean?

Comment: @KryNaC, you said you did not think that Delphi 10 Seattle was the problem since it was working in a previous version. Something that breaks a previous working function is called a regression. This is what happened here.

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few entries at Embarcadero quality portal regarding your issue. [Here is one](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12329).

It seems the error is confirmed for the original version "*Delphi 10 Seattle*" but fixed in update 1 "*Delphi 10 Seattle UD1*".

I tested the functionality successfully in "*Delphi 10 Seattle UD1*" and "*Delphi 10.1 Berlin*".

Comment: @KryNaC By contacting your local supplier, or [Embarcadero](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi). Alternatively, since this was working in XE8, if you don't need to use a later version, download that for free (registered users are eligible for earlier versions).

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a solution in this case by using `*.LNG` files , you use **Delphi 10 seattle** , so follow this steps :

- Drop `TLang` component in the form , 2 `Button` , 2 `RadioButton`.
- Make this changes:

> Button1.text = 'Add'.
>
> Button2.text = 'Open'.
>
> RadioButton1.text = 'EN'.
>
> RadioButton2.text = 'AR'.

- Double click on `TLang` , add two language **EN** and **AR**.
- click `Create a model text file` button.
- Open your TEXT file , make the changes you need (AR).
- When you finish , Save the file As eg: **AR.LNG**.
- Open your TEXT file , make the changes you need (EN).
- When you finish , Save the file As eg: **EN.LNG**.

To change the Language :

AR Lang :

```
procedure TForm1.RadioButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
LoadLangFromStrings(Lang1.LangStr['AR']);
LoadLangFromFile('YourFileLocation\AR.lng');
End;
```

EN lang :

```
procedure TForm1.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
LoadLangFromStrings(Lang1.LangStr['EN']);
LoadLangFromFile('YourFileLocation\EN.lng');
end;
```